# sum of all fields under collection on specific post

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Dataset is like this

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("6a1464430b4215046c768y66"),
   "a" : 5,
   "b" : 4,
   "c" : 2,
   "d" : 14,
   "e" : 7,
   "f" : 25,
   "g" : 85,
}
```

Now I want to do sum of all fields on this id only.
My query is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {$match:{_id: req.body.id}},
        {$project: {total: { $sum: [ "$a", "$b", "$c", "$d","$e","$f","$g" ]}}}]);
```

Using `$match`, it returns Blank Array[]. When Not use `$match` then it will return the sum, but for all not for this id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$add` as well.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match:{_id: ObjectId("6a1464430b4215046c768y66")}},
   {$project: { total: {$add: ["$a", "$b", "$c"]}}} // etc.
])
```

But `$sum` should work too. Could it be that the `$match` pipeline doesn't return any results?

I don't which driver you use, but doing it in your code it could interpret your id. But if you search directly on your database you should go with a specific `_id`

Try to execute only the match and find out:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match:{_id: ObjectId("6a1464430b4215046c768y66")}}
])
```

If the `$match` executed in your database returns a result but not through your node.js application then try this:

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match:{_id: new ObjectId(req.body.id})}},
   {$project: { total: {$add: ["$a", "$b", "$c"]}}} // etc. you could also use $sum
])
```

Comment: It not worked. again return Blank Array i.e []. when remove $match then it will return sum of all data like my query do

Comment: I didn't say remove the `$match`, I said remove the `$project` and see if the match returns any results. It's not the project that is causing the problem it is rather that you get no match

Comment: Checked. When Use Only $match returns Blank array. I think have some problem on using $match here

Comment: I think _id have some problem. I will manually pass the id like {$match:{_id: '5a151b3672d2b21dfcb01247'}},then also return Blank array

Comment: Yep I updated the answer, I think you are mixing up the node.js driver that you use in your code, with direct query on your mongodb server.

Comment: Exactly this is happening. Using Object id Error generate and says Objectid not defined

Comment: Ok so it's your mongodb driver. But I know that with some mongodb drivers it's enough if you just pass the `_id` as a string. It is probably the same case here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{$match:{_id:ObjectId("SomeId")}}`

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
{$match:{_id:ObjectId("5a153c6d4828c9f51d3adb53")}},
{$project: {total: { $sum: [ "$a", "$b", "$c", "$d","$e","$f","$g" ]}}}
])
```

Use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` to convert an `id` to `ObjectId`

output :

> {
>       "_id" : ObjectId("5a153c6d4828c9f51d3adb53"),
>       "total" : 142 }

Comment: Using Object id Error generate and says Objectid not defined on nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Its Done. Problem is not in Query. Actually Object Id problem. So convert id to object id  with the help of some mongoose logic.
First call Mongoose i.e

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

After That Under Function Just add

```
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);
```

Now Problem is solved. It convert String to Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is absolutely fine , the problem is that what you are passing the "_id" field in the query is a string but type of your "_id" if the data record is ObjectId. So you will have to first convert the string to ObjectId and then pass into "_id" field in the $match field in the query.

```
var docId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);   

db.collection.aggregate([
        {$match:{_id: docIid}},
        {$project: {total: { $sum: [ "$a", "$b", "$c", "$d","$e","$f","$g" ]}}}]);
```